Nginx 504 Getway timeout for SpringBoot 3 deployed on Kubernetes
I use SpringBoot 3 to create a application and deployed on Kubernetes. An endpoint will need to query large volume of data. When I use POSTMAN to call this endpoint, it gives me 504 Getway timeout nginx error and time-out at 3 mins. If I query smaller range of data, it works fine. This application is deployed using kubernets. below is my partially k8s.yaml:
sites:
  my-cluster:
    httpService:
      hpa:
        minReplicas: 1
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: my-app-config-map
    istiov2:
      <<: *x-istiov2
      gateway:
      - app:
          name: singlehost
          servers:
            hosts:
            - "my.server"
          httpRoutes:
          - route:
              paths:
              - prefix: "/"
              destinationHost: "myhost"
              timeout: 600s # 10 minutes timeout

I have increased timeout to 10 mins, but still will timeout at 3 mins. Is any way, I can config timeout longer? By the way, I am using webclient. Is any way whatever from springboot or nginx, I can expand the timeout? Thank you
